# Test -list files needs your permission to access your data on Google

Tags: google-apps-script

Every time I run any Google script, this message pops up.

> -- Test -list files needs your permission to access your data on Google.

I deleted it from my third party apps, but it still keeps popping up.  I was trying to run a script to gather all of the rejected emails and it wanted access more access, which I denied. Below is the script. Something is embedded somewhere and I'm not sure where.

```
function getBouncedEmails() {

    /* Written by Amit Agarwal */
    /* Email: amit@labnol.org  */

    // Write the bounced email report to a Google SpreadsheetApp
   /var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();

    // Find all emails returned via Gmail Mailer Maemon
    var query = "from:(mailer-daemon@google.com OR mailer-daemon@googlemail.com)";

    // Get the most recent 1000 bounced email messages in Gmail
    GmailApp.search(query, 0, 1000).forEach(function(thread) {
        thread.getMessages().forEach(function(message) {
            if (message.getFrom().indexOf("mailer-daemon") !== -1) {
                var body = message.getPlainBody();
                 Get the bounced email address from the body
                var matches = body.match(/Delivery to[\s\S]+?(\S+\@\S+)\s([\s\S]+?)----- Original Message/);

            }
        });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to prevent any Google Script from accessing your data.

1. Go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions
2. Click the script you wish to uninstall
3. Next click Remove and you are done.